# HandlebarsJS - How to display nested JSON

Tags: json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have this Backbone App where I display my data/json with HandlebarsJS.

Now my API returns nested JSON data:

```
{
  "Live": [
  {
  "artist_name": "some artist",
  "video_title": " some video title",
  "video_thumbnail": "some thumbnail"
  }
 ],
 "Others" : [
  {
  "artist_name": "some artist",
  "video_title": " some video title",
  "video_thumbnail": "some thumbnail"
  }
 ]
}
```

I tried to do

```
{{#each Live}}
  <div>
    <img src="{{video_thumbnail}}">
    <h2>{{video_title}}</h2>
    <h2>{{artist_name}}</h2>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

But that did not work...

Anyone who know what to do? thanks in advance...

Comment: That Handlebars template looks valid to me, what didn't work?

Comment: @idbehold it returns a blank page...

Comment: Can you post the code for your Backbone view and how you're passing the data into it?

Comment: created a simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gwn2w/1/

Comment: That fiddle has no Backbone in it at all.

Comment: I know but is it really necessary right now? Must be possible to create simple handlebars example...

Answer (score -1):

Handlebar templates can be used in two ways.
1. We can save the file with (.hbs)
2. Second way is we need the handlebar template in script tag. Provided same in [jsfiddle][1] , I have provided link, you can check the below link

```
 [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/trilokvallamkonda/cLgzf21y/13/
```